# how to get autocomplete result come up in existing select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an existing multiple select list with say data like below.

```
  <select id="Select2" size="6" multiple>
       <option>11</option>
       <option>12</option>
       <option>115</option>
       <option>116</option>
       <option>128</option>
       <option>111</option>

 </select>
```

I have an additional textbox for entering the id number.
When the user enters value in this textbox I want the existing select list to change to the result we get from autocomplete feature of jquery. So if the user enters 11

I want the select list to change to

```
      <select id="Select2" size="6" multiple>
       <option>11</option>
       <option>115</option>
       <option>116</option>
       <option>111</option>

 </select>
```

But I do not want the autocomplete select list as comes by using the autocomplete jquery.
How can I achieve that using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ac8x4/2/)

What you can do is have each `option` have an id and have a listener bound to the `keyup` event of the text input.  On each keyup event,

- the value of the text input will be compared against the ID of the option elements.
- The options that do not contain the text should have their `display` attribute set to `none`
- those that do contain the text have the `display` attribute set to `block`

  ```
  <input type = "text" id = "text_input" /> 

  <select id="select" size="6" multiple>
    <option id = '11'>11</option>
    <option id = '12'>12</option>
    <option id = '115'>115</option>
    <option id = '116'>116</option>
    <option id = '128'>128</option>
    <option id = '111'>111</option>
  </select>


  $("#text_input").on("keyup", function(){

    //get value of input
    var val = $(this).val();

    //iterate over options in the select menu
    $("#select option").each(function(){

      //if value is not contained inside an option id, hide option element
      if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf(val) == -1)
        $(this).css("display", "none");

      //otherwise, show it
      else
        $(this).css("display", "block");
    });

  });
  ```

Note that if you don't want to tie up an id attribute for this functionality, the HTML `data-` attribute and jQuery's `$(#select").data(...)` will work in place of `attr("id")`