# Selecting only the options not wrapped inside span to move to next select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is related to my earlier question here:

[how to get autocomplete result come up in existing select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984216/how-to-get-autocomplete-result-come-up-in-existing-select-list)

But then the style display none does not work in ie. I am using only IE.
I was able to workaround the issue and was able to hide the option items inside spans.

But the problem now is suppose i enter 160 for ids I get the three option in the left select list.
Now when I use the '>>' button all the hidden items also move.How do I select only the three options that came after filter and not all.

My html code is like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete Extension - Auto Select Option</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.fn.hideOption = function () {
            jQuery(this).wrap('<span class="hideOption" style="display: none;" />');
        }

        $.fn.showOption = function () {
            if (jQuery(this).parent('span.hideOption').length)
                jQuery(this).unwrap();
        }
        $("#txtid").on("keyup", function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $("#idLeftValues option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf(val) == -1)
                    $(this).hideOption();
                else
                    $(this).showOption();
            });
        });
        $("#btnidLeft").click(function () {
            var selectedItem = $("#idRightValues option:selected ").hasClass("hideOption");
            $("#idLeftValues").append(selectedItem);
        });

        $("#btnidRight").click(function () {
            var selectedItem = $("#idLeftValues option:selected");
            $("#idRightValues").append(selectedItem);
        });

        $("#btnidLeftAll").click(function () {
            $("#idRightValues option").prop('selected', true);
            var selectedItem = $("#idRightValues option:selected");
            $("#idLeftValues").append(selectedItem);
        });

        $("#btnidRightAll").click(function () {
            $("#idLeftValues option").prop('selected', true);
            var selectedItem = $("#idLeftValues option:selected");
            $("#idRightValues").append(selectedItem);
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .innercontainer > DIV  {
float: left;
padding: 4px;
}

.containerid {
padding: 8px;
float: left;
width:600px;
font-weight:bold;
}

#row3 SELECT, #row3 INPUT[type="text"]  
{
 width: 140px;
}

.lstBtns 
{

width: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

.lbBtn
{
width:25px;
text-align:center;
padding-left:0px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="contid">
        <span>
           id: 
            <input id="txtid" type="text" /></span>
        <br />
        <div id="row3" class="innercontainer">
            <div>
                <select id="idLeftValues" size="8" multiple>
                    <option id="140546">140546</option>
                    <option id= "150978" >150978</option>
                    <option id= "160968">160968 </option>
                    <option id= "160978">160978</option>
                    <option id= "160988">160988</option>
                    <option id= "170978">170978</option>
                    <option  id= "170979">170979</option>
                    <option  id= "170980">170980</option>
                    <option  id= "170981">170981</option>
                    <option  id= "170982">170982</option>
                    <option  id= "170991">170991</option>
                    <option  id= "170992">170992</option>
                    <option  id= "170993">170993</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="lstBtns">
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="btnidRight" class="lbBtn" value="&nbsp;&gt;" />
                <input type="button" id="btnidRightAll" class="lbBtn" value="&gt;&gt;" />
                <input type="button" id="btnidLeft" class="lbBtn" value="&nbsp;&lt;" />
                <input type="button" id="btnidLeftAll" class="lbBtn" value="&lt;&lt;" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="idRightValues" size="8" multiple>                      
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The fiddle link is here
    http://jsfiddle.net/0808/GumFy/

Comment: stop hiding the options and instead remove them from the select. all your problems will be solved. http://jsfiddle.net/GumFy/1/

Comment: Fixing problems with duct tape usually leads to more problems.

Comment: Next you'll just need to handle the options in a separate array so that the fact that some of them are removed doesn't mess with the rest of the logic.

Comment: But, if you want to just continue bandaiding, filter the selection to only options that are direct descendants of a select element.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I did not know about the detach function yet. That works great. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am new to jquery. I am confused about what is happening in this line in your attached fiddle:  $("#idLeftValues").append($options).children().each(function () {
                   if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf(val) == -1) $(this).detach();
                });